# Possibilities for the number of integers in an infinite arithmetic or geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

> (a) Determine all nonnegative integers $r$ such that it is possible for an infinite arithmetic sequence to contain exactly $r$ terms that are integers. Prove your answer.
>
> (b) Determine all nonnegative integers $r$ such that it is possible for an infinite geometric sequence to contain exactly $r$ terms that are integers. Prove your answer.

Comment: Any thoughts?  For a) can you, say, come up with an arithmetic progression with no integers?  How about exactly one?  exactly two?

Answer (score 1):

For (b),
consider
$2^{r-n}$
for which only the
first
$r$ terms are integers.

Answer (score 1):

(a) There are two variants:

1. r=0. This happens, for example, with a series $\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{2}d$
2. r=1. Look at the series $0 + \sqrt{2}d$
   In fact, suppose that $a$ and $a+sd$ are integers. Than all the numbers of the type $a + ksd$, where $k$ is integer, are also integers, so $r=\infty$

(b)

1. Look at the series $\sqrt{2}\exp^d$. It doesn't contain any integers.
2. Now look at the series $\exp^d$. It contains only one integer.
3. In fact the values $r$ can be whatever you want. Let $a = q^{r-1}$, $e = \frac{p}{q}$, $GCD(p,q)=1$. Then the only integers in the series $ae^d$ would be:

$$
a = q^{r-1}
$$

$$
ae = \frac{p}{q^{r-2}}
$$
$$
...
$$
$$
ae^{r-1} = p
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** For $(a)$ show that if an arithmetic progression contains two integers, the ratio must be a rational number.

**Hint 2** If an arithmetic progression has ratio $r=\frac{k}{n}$ and a term $a_l \in \mathbb Z$ then you can make 
$$a_{l+m}=a_l + m \frac{k}{n}$$
an integer by setting $m$ to ......